# Is a 'method' which is not valid in the given context error

Tags: c#

This is an example form the "Head First CSharp - page 113"
I'm getting the following error

> Error  1   'Guys.Form1.joesCashLabel(object, System.EventArgs)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context c:\temp\Guys\Guys\Form1.cs  20  12  Guys

And the same with the other two labels

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guys
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Guy Joe;
        Guy Bob;
        int Bank = 100;

        public void UpdateForm()
        {
           joesCashLabel.Text = Joe.Name + "$" + Joe.Money;
            bobsCashLabel.Text = Bob.Name + "$" + Bob.Money;
            bankCashLabel.Text = "Bank has" + Bank;
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Guy Bob = new Guy();
            Bob.Name = "Bob";
            Bob.Money =100;

            Guy Joe = new Guy();
            Joe.Name = "Joe";
            Joe.Money =50;

            UpdateForm();

        }

        private void joesCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bobsCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bankCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Bank >= 10) 
            {
                Bank -= Joe.ReceiveMoney(10);
                UpdateForm();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No money in the bank");
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bank = Bank + Bob.GiveMoney(5);
            UpdateForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see by looking at your code, `joesCashLabel` is in fact a method.  And you are using it as though it were a textbox.

Comment: In your project explorer, there might be a file called `Form1.Designer.cs`.  Although you should never ever **change** the code in the designer file, we might be able to glean some information from reading it.  can you post the code from that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define two types in same project with same name, here you have three controls and three events with same name. so remove the below methods to compile without errors.

```
private void joesCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e){}

private void bobsCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e){}

private void bankCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

If you want to add events make sure you are following naming standard like `ControlName_EventName`

Comment: I've realized something - I have removed "Guy" from the public Form1()
        { Guy Bob = new Guy();}
and made it so.... Bob = new Guy(); and now it works. I have declared a variable twice. This was the mistake

Answer (score 4):

it's a method(an event at that),

```
private void joesCashLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

but you're using it as a variable

```
joesCashLabel.Text = Joe.Name + "$" + Joe.Money;
```

My guess, is that there's some sort of label that that event is supposed to be associated with.