# Getting error while making SQLite Connection in Xamarin PCL

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following this tutorial for SQLite practice in Xamarin:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-sqlite--cms-23020

Now I am stuck here in

public RandomThoughtDatabase ()
        {
            _connection = DependencyService.Get"ISQLite" ().GetConnection ();
        }

`ISQLite` is an interface in PCL

its giving this error

**Error CS0119  'DependencyService.Get(DependencyFetchTarget)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context  LocalStorage**

Comment: Did you mean to write `DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>()`? Also do you happen to have an `ISQLite.GetConnection` property, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548097/is-a-method-which-is-not-valid-in-the-given-context-error) issue?

Comment: DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection(); it works.

Comment: Bundle of Thanks :(

Comment: yeah . Actually i am new to Xamarin . Shifting from Android Studio To Xamarin

Answer (score 2):

Use the following instead:

```
public RandomThoughtDatabase () { _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection(); }
```